# Looking for one-click VPN for Mac that sits in the tray?

Tags: osx, vpn

I was using this tool at some point in the past.

Right now I cannot locate it.

One click VPN connection aimed at less-technical users using WiFi from libraries and coffee-shops...

Comment: By the way, the [Opera browser](https://www.opera.com) for macOS [offers a built-in VPN](https://www.opera.com/computer/features/free-vpn) feature, free-of-cost. Of course, it applies only to the traffic from within that browser app.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about tunnelblick.

This is what I am using, and it is indeed a one click that sits in the tray after setup.

For OpenVPN all you need is the .ovpn file.

here is the link:
https://tunnelblick.net/

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you are talking about [Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client-v4-x/model.html)? Here is what it looks like just after I launch it, you input the server address and your credentials and that's really all it needs!

[image: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client OSX Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

TunnelBear is one, but with its cutesy animations, you'd be likely to remember using it.
https://www.tunnelbear.com/

Comment: Please include a screenshot, thanks! And price informaton. See http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality